# no puedo validar un objeto de array con for of

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches ya si esto no se como hacerlo, pero lo intente y es tener una validacion, si La conducta del estudiante es true y su nota es mayor a 10, entonces se imprima por consola un mensaje diciendo "El estudiante pasa de curso", en cambio, si la conducta del estudiante es false y sin importar su nota se imprima por consola "El estudiante reprueba el curso", y si la nota es menor a 10, tambien imprima "El estudiante reprueba el curso, se que se puede hacer con un :"for of" pero no se como hacerlo

```js
const estudiantes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Boby",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 17,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
      conducta: true
    }
,
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Eliezer",
      apellido: "Gil",
      nota: 16,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",  
            conducta: false
    },
      {
      id: 3 ,
      nombre: "Fabiana",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 18,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
            conducta: true
        },
    {
      id: 4,
      nombre: "Rebeca",
      apellido: "Mendez",
      nota: 20,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
            conducta: true
```

```js
const validacion = (estudiantes) => {

    for( notas of nota){
   if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10){
       console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"-Aprobado")
       break
   }
   if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota =< 10)
   console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"- No Aprobado")
       break
}
validacion(estudiantes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Debería quedar algo así:

```
 const validacion = (estudiantes) => {

    for(const alumno of estudiantes){
    if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10){
       console.log(alumno.nombre+" "+alumno.apellido+" - Aprobado")
   } else {
    console.log(alumno.nombre+" "+alumno.apellido+" - No Aprobado")
 }
 }
 }
 validacion(estudiantes)
```

Comment: Recuerda por favor en ambas preguntas marcar el visto al costado de las respuestas si te sirvieron. Gracias.

Comment: Vi que ya pusiste como solucionada la otra, te agradezco cerrar esta también, muchas gracias, nuestra participación tanto preguntando como contestando ayudan a otros!